# Memory Error while creating Data frame from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running a SQL query using cx_oracle in python, and the result of the query is a list. The dimension of list if 180 columns * 200,000+ rows.
Whenever I try to convert it into a data frame using pd.DataFrame I run into a Memory Error.
For now as a solution I've tried to breakdown my query by putting filters, or query only a few columns etc, which works out. But then if I change some filters I again run into the error, and I can't always be sure of how many rows a query will return.

So I'm looking for any alternative data structures/library/packages which can be used. Or anyway where I can handle this within Pandas?
As I'm doing data analysis using Pandas, so I would prefer if there is a way to handle this in Pandas rather than another library.

The fields in the list is either float,string or timestamp format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read data *directly* into Pandas DataFrame:

```
import cx_Oracle   #  pip install cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host_or_scan_address:1521/ORACLE_SERVIVE_NAME')

df = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name where ...', engine)
```

PS you may also want to make use of the [`chunksize` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)...

Comment: Thank you I was able to query larger sizes using this. Is there a limit for the number of rows one can query using sqlalchemy? or any form of restriction you're aware of?

Comment: @user23564, AFAIK it's just your RAM size ;-)